# Check master ros node is started C++

Tags: ros, c++, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is there a way in C++ to check whether the master ros node is setup? I initially believed ros::init() would return false, but the return type is false...

I have quickly looked on the internet and could find nothing...

Thanks ;)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236678/check-master-ros-node-is-started-c++/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-06-13**:
Anyone for this question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-13**:
Please don't post comments or updates as answers. It can be confusing when looking at the questions list (it appears as if the question has already at least one answer). I've moved your answer to the comment section, but please keep it in mind for next time.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-06-13**:
got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use [ros::master::check()](http://docs.ros.org/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1master.html#a6428e7e3468e4e9ab69b75f75d63510d).

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "master_test");
    ros::Time::init();
    while (!ros::master::check())
    {
        std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
        ros::Duration(0.5).sleep();
    }
    std::cout << "master started!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2016-06-14**:
That works fine, thanks!